# Stars properties evolution and the sun

Tags: stars

Is it possible that you can touch a star in outer space without getting burned or hurt?

Comment: What does your question have to do with the properties or evolution of the sun? To answer your question:  if you were close enough to touchh a star, the tidal forces would shread you to pieces regardless of temperature. Disregarding that, touching a main sequence star would always lead to you being incinerated. Temperature wise you might get away with caressing a brown dwarf, or in x trillion years a black dwarf, which is a white dwarf that has cooled down to the point where it has the same temperature as the cosmic microwave background radition.

Comment: Oh, and astronomy.stackexchange is probably a better fit for your question. This portal is concerned with the exploration of space, and not astronomy per se.